# Get sub projects Project Server Interface

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, project-server, ms-project-server-2010

Is it possible to retrieve list of subprojects using PSI (project server interface)? I found Relations datatable in ProjectDataSet but it is always empty. Maybe there is an easier way to get guids of subprojects than using PSI?

Comment: MSDN says that Relations table is used to map tables in dataset, not projects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.projectdataset.relations_di_pj14mref.aspx
Try to check Task data table. It will contain summary tasks for each sub project. Maybe it also contains sub project id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN says that Relations table is used to map tables in dataset, not projects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.projectdataset.relations_di_pj14mref.aspx. Try to check Task data table. It will contain summary tasks for each sub project. Maybe it also contains sub project id.

Comment: TASK_IS_SUBPROJ tells if task is a sub project and task.TASK_EXT_PROJ_UID is the guid of the subproject